# Need to start with Block device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

With char device driver there is no issue, i am able to write a basic char device driver.but can any body help me to write block device driver,can any body give me the first block device driver code for better understanding which i can test on my machine.

Comment: Have you looked in to LDD yet? It's a free online now. https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Comment: I am new in LDD and in LDD3 i didnt get any direct program that i can compile and run and can understand at initial level.there is big fundamentals for Queueing and all stuff.(because in LDD3 for char device i get code directly)

Comment: [Here](http://lwn.net/Articles/58720/) is simple block device driver to get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [the LDD3 chapter on block devices](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch16.pdf) for the explanations, then [some sample code](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/05/04/a-simple-block-driver-for-linux-kernel-2-6-31/) based on it.